# Python3: shell quoting less complicated than shlex.quote() output?

Tags: python-3.x, quoting, shlex

In `python3.8`, I have this code:

```
import shlex
item = "ABC'DEF"
quoteditem = shlex.quote(item)
print(quoteditem)
```

This is the output:

> 'ABC'"'"'DEF'

It's difficult to discern the double and single quotes here on this web page, so this is a description of what is printed:

```
single-quote
ABC
single-quote
double-quote
single-quote
double-quote
single-quote
DEF
single-quote
```

This is, of course, a correct shell quoting, but it is not the only possible shell quoting, and it is overly complex.

Another possibility is simply this:

> "ABC'DEF"

And here's a second possibility:

> ABC\'DEF

I much prefer these simpler versions. I know how to write `python` code to convert the complicated version into one of these simpler forms, but I'm wondering if there might be an already existing `python` function which can perform this kind of simpler shell quoting.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort-of an answer. It doesn't provide "*... an already existing `python` function which can perform this kind of simpler shell quoting*", as I requested, since it now seems like such a quoting function doesn't exist in `python`. However, it does show how I coded a quoting mechanism that provides simpler output (for `python-3.6` or above):

```
def shellquote(item):
    if not item:
        return "''"
    # Pre-escape any escape characters                                                                                                                    
    item = item.replace('\\', r'\\')
    if "'" not in item:
        # Contains no single quotes, so we can                                                                                                        
        # single-quote the output.                                                                                                                    
        return f"'{item}'"
    else:
        # Enclose in double quotes. We must escape                                                                                                    
        # "$" and "!", which which normally trigger                                                                                                   
        # expansion in double-quoted strings in shells.                                                                                               
        # If it contains double quotes, escape them, also.                                                                                               
        item = item.replace(r'$', r'\$') \
                   .replace(r'!', r'\!') \
                   .replace(r'"', r'\"')
        return f'"{item}"'
```

For earlier versions of `python` which don't support f-strings, `format` can be used instead of those f-strings.

Here are some examples. The lefthand column shows the assignment statement of the `pythonString` variable within the `python` program. The righthand column shows what will then appear on the terminal when `print(shellquote(pythonString))` is invoked from within the `python` program:

```
pythonString='ABC"DEF'       printed output: 'ABC"DEF'
pythonString="ABC'DEF"       printed output: "ABC'DEF"
pythonString='ABC\'DEF'      printed output: "ABC'DEF"
pythonString="ABC\"DEF"      printed output: 'ABC"DEF'
pythonString='ABC\\"DEF'     printed output: 'ABC\\"DEF'
pythonString="ABC\\'DEF"     printed output: "ABC\\'DEF"
pythonString="AB'C$DEF"      printed output: "AB'C\$DEF"
pythonString='AB\'C$DEF'     printed output: "AB'C\$DEF"
pythonString='AB"C$DEF'      printed output: 'AB"C$DEF'
pythonString="AB\"C$DEF"     printed output: 'AB"C$DEF'
pythonString='A\'B"C$DEF'    printed output: "A'B\"C\$DEF"
pythonString='A\\\'B"C$DEF'  printed output: "A\\'B\"C\$DEF"
```

This is not the only way that the shell quoting could be performed, but at least the output is simpler than what comes out of `shlex.quote` in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

[shlex.quote](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/58277de8e651df287ceae053eeb321c0f8406a1b/Lib/shlex.py#L325) is optimized for performance, so the output is machine-readable, but less pretty for human eyes. producing a "pretty" string is slower

when you wrap the string in double-quotes (for a shell), you also need to escape expressions like `$x` or `$(x)` or `!x`

```py
import re

_shell_quote_is_unsafe = re.compile(r'[^\w@%+=:,./-]', re.ASCII).search
# note: [^...] = negated char class -> safe chars are \w@%+=:,./-

_shell_quote_replace = re.compile(r'([\\$"!])', re.ASCII).sub

def shell_quote(s: str):
    """
    Return a shell-escaped version of the string *s*.
    Wrap string in double-quotes when necessary.
    Based on shlex.quote (wrap string in single-quotes)
    """
    if not s:
        return '""'
    if _shell_quote_is_unsafe(s) is None:
        return s
    return '"' + _shell_quote_replace(r"\\\1", s) + '"'

# test
assert shell_quote('a"b\\c$d$(e)!f\tg\nh\ri') == '"a\\"b\\\\c\\$d\\$(e)\\!f\tg\nh\ri"'
```